# Where does it first talk about saying HaNotein Re'ach Tov BaPeirot

Tags: halacha, blessing, torah-study, tractate-brachot, orach-chaim

BH

Where does it first talk about saying the Bracha HaNotein Re'ach Tov BaPeirot?

Comment: See Brachot 43b

Answer (score 2):

Berachos 43b

> אָמַר מָר זוּטְרָא: הַאי מַאן דְּמוֹרַח בְּאֶתְרוֹגָא אוֹ בְּחַבּוּשָׁא אוֹמֵר: "בָּרוּךְ שֶׁנָּתַן רֵיחַ טוֹב בַּפֵּירוֹת".
>
> Mar Zutra said: One who smells a citron [etrog] or a quince recites: Blessed…who gave pleasant fragrance in fruits.